# El Gamal Cryptosystem Proof, Step-by-Step Explanation Needed. I feel like I don't understand what I have on this proof

Tags: algorithm-design, elgamal-encryption

Can someone provide a good and thorough explanation of the El Gamal proof? Basically, I need a step-by-step breakdown of what is happening at each important part in the algorithm.

I haven't been able to find any good notes on El Gamala that explain the proof in an easy to understand format.

Here is the proof in this image:

[image: EL GAMAL PROOF REQUIRES EXPLANATION]

Comment: Generally when people talk about the "proof of ElGamal encryption" they refer to the proof of security. What you have there is just the derivation that shows that it is *correct*, i.e. that decryption actually works. Are you aware of that or is that part of the confusion?

Comment: Oh dear, I must be so confused then. This is what I took from my professor's notes and I assumed it was the proof because it is labeled as such.

Comment: I think I mean that I need an explanation of the derivation, which is the image posted in the body of my message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, we should make clear *what we're proving here*. The derivation you're showing is part of a proof of *correctness* of ElGamal encryption, *not security*.

Perfect correctness (also referred to as completeness) of a public key encryption scheme is defined as follows.

Let $(\mathsf{Gen},\mathsf{Enc},\mathsf{Dec})$ be a public key encryption scheme. The scheme is said to be perfectly correct if it holds that for any security parameter $n\in\mathbb{N}$, any key pair $(\mathsf{ek},\mathsf{dk})\gets\mathsf{Gen}(1^n)$, any message $m$ from the message space, and any ciphertext $c \gets \mathsf{Enc}(\mathsf{ek},m)$ it holds that $\mathsf{Dec}(\mathsf{dk},c)=m$.

To see whether ElGamal encryption is correct, we first recall the definition of ElGamal encryption. I will try to follow the notation in your notes as close as possible. From the notes it's not clear what kind of group is being used. But $e_1$ is a generator of some subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$. Let $q$ be the order of that subgroup. (If $e_1$ is a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$, then $q=p-1$, if we are in a safe prime setting, then $q=(p-1)/2$ and prime.

\begin{align}
&\mathsf{Gen}(1^n) && \mathsf{Enc}(e_2,P) && \mathsf{Dec}(d,(c_1,c_2))\\
&d\gets\mathbb{Z}_q&&r \gets \mathbb{Z}_q&&P' := c_2\cdot (c_1^d)^{-1} \bmod p\\
&e_2 := e_1^d \bmod p&&c_1:= e_1^r\bmod p&&\text{return }P'\\
&\text{return } (e_2,d)&&c_2 := P\cdot e_2^r\bmod p&\\
&&&\text{return } (c_1,c_2)&&\\
\end{align}

To verify that the scheme is correct, we need to verify that for any choice of key pair, and message it always holds that $\mathsf{Dec}(d,\mathsf{Enc}(e_2,P)) = P$. This is where the derivation you're looking at comes in.

\begin{align}
 P' =& c_2\cdot (c_1^d)^{-1} \bmod p \tag{1}\\
=& c_2\cdot (e_1^{rd})^{-1} \bmod p\tag{2}\\
=& P\cdot e_2^r\cdot (e_1^{rd})^{-1} \bmod p\tag{3}\\
=& P\cdot e_1^{rd}\cdot (e_1^{rd})^{-1} \bmod p\tag{4}\\
=& P\cdot e_1^{rd}\cdot e_1^{-rd} \bmod p\tag{5}\\
=& P\cdot e_1^{rd-rd} \bmod p\tag{6}\\
=& P \bmod p\tag{7}\\
\end{align}

Now let's go through this line by line.

1. In line (1) we simply have the definition of the decryption algorithm.
2. In line (2) we use the definition of $c_1 = e_1^r\bmod p$ from the encryption algorithm and replace $c_1$ by its definition.
3. In line (3) we do exactly the same with $c_2$ and replace it with its definition $c_2 := P\cdot e_2^r\bmod p$ from the encryption algorithm.
4. In line (4) we now look at the key generation algorithm and replace $e_2$ by its definition from there $e_2 := e_1^d \bmod p$. Note that we have not changed anything. We have simply replaced the variables $c_1,c_2,e_2$ by their respective definitions.
5. In line (5) we use a basic [rule of exponentiation](https://mathinsight.org/exponentiation_basic_rules), namely that $(x^a)^b = x^{a\cdot b}$, therefore $(e_1^{rd})^{-1} = e_1^{-rd}$.
6. In line (6) we again use a basic [rule of exponentiation](https://mathinsight.org/exponentiation_basic_rules), namely that $x^a\cdot x^b = x^{a+ b}$, therefore $e_1^{rd}\cdot e_1^{-rd} = e_1^{rd-rd}$.
7. Since $rd-rd=0$ and anything raised to the $0$th power equals the identity, we are left with $P\cdot 1 \bmod p$ and thereby, since $1$ is the identity of the group with $P$ in line (7).

Since this derivation makes no assumptions whatsoever about $P,d,e_2,c_1$ and $c_2$, besides that they were generated according to the above definition of ElGamal encryption, it holds for any choice of key-pair and any plaintext $P$.

The derivation thus shows that decryption always works and results in the same plaintext that was encrypted, thus showing that the encryption scheme is in fact correct.

What it does *not* show is anything about the security of the scheme.

Comment: This is amazing and exactly what I needed. However, I think my professor is using this as a proof for El Gamal's encryption and decryption process and why it works, and I don't think she is using it as a proof of the security of El Gamal. She didn't really specify, but thanks for clearing this up.